# getting syntax error in case statement in shell

Tags: shell, case

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=$1
vcva=$2
esx=$3
pxe=$4
setup=$5




#If branch is Vsphere-2015

if [ "$branch" == "vsphere2015"];then

      echo " Running Bats for Vsphere-2015 with the following details ."



if [ ! "vcva" ];then

    echo "VCVA Build is $2 "
    echo "ESX Build is $4 "
    echo "pxe info is $5 "


#If all the setups has to be run

setup=$5
case "$setup" in "all")

        echo "runnning all setups on Vsphere-2015."
        vpshere2015_primary
        vpshere2015_M1N1
        vpshere2015_M2N1                               =======> these are methods 
        vpshere2015_legacy
    ;;
```

I'm new to shell and after this piece of code  getting

bat.sh: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'at.sh: line 38:`      ;;

I want to run some functions depending upon the inputs given by the user in command line

Comment: You also need a space before the closing `]` -- `[ "$branch" == "vsphere2015"]` should be `[ "$branch" == "vsphere2015" ]`. The reason: the `[` command demands its last argument must be `]`, and arguments are separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The `case` satatement must end with `esac`

Syntax of `case` is

```
case EXPRESSION in CASE1) COMMAND-LIST;; CASE2) COMMAND-LIST;; ... CASEN) COMMAND-LIST;; esac
```

So here it should be

```
case "$setup" in "all")

        echo "runnning all setups on Vsphere-2015."
        vpshere2015_primary
        vpshere2015_M1N1
        vpshere2015_M2N1                               =======> these are methods 
        vpshere2015_legacy
    ;;

esac
```

here once `$setup` is matched with `all` the entire command list is excecuted

Also, it is not restricted that you should place `all` in quote `" "`

case "$setup" in all)

```
        echo "runnning all setups on Vsphere-2015."
        vpshere2015_primary
        vpshere2015_M1N1
        vpshere2015_M2N1                               =======> these are methods 
        vpshere2015_legacy
    ;;

esac
```

will also work fine

Answer (score 1):

You just have to close all the if's (with "**fi**") and the case statement (with "**esac**").

I thing you also have to change the

```
if [ ! "vcva" ];then
```

into

```
if [ ! -z "$vcva" ] ; then
```

It will result something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

branch=$1
vcva=$2
esx=$3
pxe=$4
setup=$5

#If branch is Vsphere-2015
if [ "$branch" == "vsphere2015" ];then
  echo " Running Bats for Vsphere-2015 with the following details ."
  if [ ! -z "$vcva" ];then
    echo "VCVA Build is $2 "
    echo "ESX Build is $4 "
    echo "pxe info is $5 "

    #If all the setups has to be run
    setup=$5
    case "$setup" in 
      "all")    
        echo "runnning all setups on Vsphere-2015."
        vpshere2015_primary
        vpshere2015_M1N1
        vpshere2015_M2N1
        vpshere2015_legacy
      ;;
      *) 
        echo "default action goes here"
      ;;
    esac
  fi # close second if
fi # close first if
```